# ajax no response in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to take some simple exercise about ajax in CI.
But no response... I had tried to set the breakpoint alert("aa") and it failed; 
But the alarm is worked ahead or behind the ajax code.
Could some one help to fix it?Many thanks.
Here is the code

```
View

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ajax example-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function AJAX_call() {
a_val  = $('[name="a"]').val();
b_val  = $('[name="b"]').val();

AJAX_url = '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/ajax_example/AJAX_calc";?>';

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url : AJAX_url,
data:  {a : a_val,  b : b_val },
dataType: "json",
success: function(data2) {alert("aa");$('#result').html(data2.result); }
}); 

}</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="AJAX_call();">
<label>Enter A</label>
<input type="text" name="a" />
<label>Enter B</label>
<input type="text" name="b" />
Result:
<div id='result'>The Result Will Be Shown Here</div>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
<?php 

class Ajax_example extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $view_params="";
            $this->load->view('ajax_view',$view_params);
    }
    function AJAX_calc() {


if (!$this->input->is_AJAX_request()) exit ('none AJAX calls rejected!'); 


$a = $this->input->post('a');
$b = $this->input->post('b');
$result = (int) $a * (int) $b; 
$data = array('result'=> $result);
echo json_encode($data);
return;

}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call your AJAX_url directly (i.e. does your routing work)? What happens if you remove your check on is_AJAX_request()?

Comment: Please open up the Networking tab in your web browsers' developers console and refresh the web page and look for your call to `AJAX_calc` and click on it. Then check out the tabs labeled `Headers` `Preview` and `Response` to see exactly what your URL is giving back to your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

you got 2 problems with your code :

1. you put the ajax call `onsubmit` which will submit the whole page and lose your ajax result
2. there was something worng with your inner attribute selector, better to make it with id

your js function will be :

```
    function AJAX_call() {
     a_val  = $('#a').val();
     b_val  = $('#b').val();

    AJAX_url = '<?php echo base_url()."remote/AJAX_calc";?>';

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : AJAX_url,
    data:  {a : a_val,  b : b_val },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data2) {alert("aa");$('#result').html(data2.result); }
     }); 

    }
```

and your html form will be  :

```
    <form >
    <label>Enter A</label>
    <input type="text" id="a" value="" />
    <label>Enter B</label>
    <input type="text" id="b" value="" />
    Result:
    <div id='result'>The Result Will Be Shown Here</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="AJAX_call();">Calculate</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your view file `ajax_view` with the below one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ajax example-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function AJAX_call(event) {
a_val  = $('[name="a"]').val();
b_val  = $('[name="b"]').val();

AJAX_url = '<?php echo base_url()."index.php/ajax_example/AJAX_calc";?>';

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url : AJAX_url,
data:  {a : a_val,  b : b_val },
dataType: "json",
success: function(data2) {alert("aa");$('#result').html(data2.result); }
}); 

event.preventDefault();
}</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="AJAX_call(event);">
<label>Enter A</label>
<input type="text" name="a" />
<label>Enter B</label>
<input type="text" name="b" />
Result:
<div id='result'>The Result Will Be Shown Here</div>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here `event.preventDefault()` method is used in `AJAX_call` function. If this method is called, the default action of the event (reloading the page) will not be triggered.